# What makes React-Perfect-Scrollbar fail on an element with a height not specified in pixels?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I am working on a chat app whose UI is made with React 18.

The app has a sidebar containing user profiles. The app is no taller then the browser window, so the list of user profiles has to be scrollable if necessary.

[image]

For this purpose, in the `UsersList.jsx` [React-Perfect-Scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-perfect-scrollbar):

```
import './_usersList.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function UsersList() {

  const API_URL = 'https://randomuser.me/api';
  const location = useLocation();
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const getUsers = async () => {
    const { data: { results } } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/?&results=20&inc=id,name,email,picture`, {
    });

    setUsers(results);
  }

  const usersList = () => {
    return users.map(user => (
      <li className="d-table-row w-100">
        <div className="user-image-container d-table-cell">
          <img src={user.picture.thumbnail} alt={`user.name.first user.name.last`} className="rounded-circle" />
        </div>
        <div className="text d-table-cell">
          <h3 className="display-name m-0">{user.name.first} {user.name.last}</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
    ))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, [location])

  return (
    <div className="chat-users">
      <PerfectScrollbar>
        <ul className="users-list list-unstyled m-0 d-table w-100">
          { usersList() }
        </ul>
      </PerfectScrollbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In `_usersList.css`, instead of a fixed height for the `<div className="chat-users">` element, I have:

```
.chat-users {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
}
```

This is because I need the element to stretch across all the available space.

But there is a problem. Unless there is a fixed height in pixels (e.g. `height: 400px;`) on the element, the scrollbar is not rendered, even if necessary.

The problem is fixed for mobile *only*, if I add `overflow-y: auto`, like so:

```
.chat-users {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

But it persists on desktop.

There is a sandbox with the code **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-cloud-wmf2jn)**.

###### What is the cause of this problem and what is the most reliable fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.chat-users {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I replaced it with above css and its showing me vertical scrollbar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by doing the following:

Adding  `overflow-y: auto` for all resolutions.

```
.chat-users {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And a *calculated* height for desktop:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .chat-users {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 144px);
  }
}
```